# fopen does not deal with more than 60 files at the same time

Tags: c, windows, file-io, fopen

I need to have more than 60 text files opened at the same time in my C program. However, it seems that fopen is not able to handle more than 60 files simultaneously. I am programming in Windows environment.

I use the following fopen statement:

```
fopen(fileName.c_str(),"wt");
```

Where fileName is the path of my txt file, name which changes inside a loop along 100 files. Does anybody know any trick to make this work? Or any alternative?

Comment: First of all you might want to check `errno` when `fopen` fails. Also, I guess you are on Windows?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot have only a few recently used files open? Then close old ones and open new ones when necessary.

Comment: Yes Joachim, I am using windows. I will try errno.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/870224/694733

Comment: user694733, my algorithm needs to have all these files opened, so I cannot close them.

Comment: Why does your algorithm require that, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: It is a very complicated algorithm, and I cannot change it (more than 6000 code lines).

Comment: @user694733 I once ran into my limit of 1024, when I used `mmap` to map a whole bunch of tables into memory. All tables together was too big for the maximum file size.

Answer (score 2):

If you issue the bash shell command:

```
ulimit -n
```

you'll see that 60 is your limit for open file handles.  You can change it with:

```
ulimit -n 256
```

Note: there're soft (`-S`) and hard (`-H`) limits you can see with `-Sn` and `-Hn`, you can change your soft limit up to your hard limit.

Comment: That's my guess as well, but 60 (64 probably) is quite low as open files limit. For example my Linux box has 1024.

Comment: 256 for my Mac, but certainly plausible it is lower on his rig.

Comment: I forgot to say that I am in Windows. How can I change it in there?

Answer (score 2):

There's actually **two** things that constrain how many files you can have open at any time:

1. The environment limit specified by `ulimit -n`.
2. The C runtime library. I know of several that limit you to 256 file handles (Sun to name one)

Your current limit is probably 63 once you take into account STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR already being opened, and I don't *know* of a system that goes that low so it's probably your `ulimit` but you need to be aware of the other limit.

On windows you can use `_setmaxstdio(n)` but in the default case you should still be able to open 512 files. so I'm still a little confused as to why you only get 60 odd unless you open each file about 8 times...

Comment: Tom, my C runtime library allows 1024 files, so it must be the environment limit. About the environment limit, is it enough with ulimit -100 statement?

Comment: I don't think ulimit applies to windows

Comment: Sorry, I meant _setmaxstdio(n). I will try it.