# Fopen() failed to open a file

Tags: c++, file, fopen, handle, file-descriptor

I'm working in win 7,64-bit,c++.
I have a multi-threaded program.
My program open and close files repeatedly, I checked and I'm closing all of the files that I open.
but after some time the program runs and I try to use `fopen` I get the error `"too many open files"`.

Is there any way to print the open files?
Is there any way to clean all the handles?(without closing the module)

thanks for the help!

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: how many threads are running at the same time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870173/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-open-files-in-windows   You must have a LOT of open files.

Comment: Download processexplorer, run, select your process, in the menu select view/lower pane view/handles.

Comment: You are calling fclose() on the open files at some point, too?

Comment: The code is to big to post here . Yes I'm calling fclose

Comment: I used after failing to open the file the command _fcloseall() and the return value was 509 is there any function to see in run time the open files/handles? Without using process explorer.

Comment: You need to start debugging your program, not trying to work around the failure.