# Is it possible to ensure a file is closed without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: python

I am reading some data from a .txt file in Python using the following:

```
fileData = open("file.txt", "rb").read()
```

I know that you should always close opened files, and I assume in this case the file remains open. Is there a way to close the file without assigning it to a variable?

I'd like to avoid:

```
openedFile = open("file.txt", "rb")
fileData = openedFile.read()
openedFile.close()
```

And also:

```
with open("file.txt", "rb") as openedFile:
    fileData = openedFile.read()
```

It might not be possible, in which case okay, but just making sure.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `with` pattern?  That's the easy way of doing it.

Comment: I'd add to what @Samwise has written: using with is _exactly_ the way of doing it.

Comment: @accdias, `read` returns a string.  That's what you'd be calling the `close` method on.

Comment: You are right. I wrote it without thinking about it.

Comment: I´m wondering if `pathlib.Path(´somefile.txt´).read_text()` closes the file after reading it.

Comment: @accdias According to [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591569/12299000), yes, pathlib does that exactly.

Comment: @accdias It must, otherwise it would leak a file descriptor.

Comment: So maybe it is an option for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. The `with` statement version is the idiomatic way to write it.

Though I would shorten `openedFile` to `file` or even `f`. Rule of thumb: The smaller the scope of a variable the shorter its name can be. Save the long names for long-lived identifiers.

```
with open("file.txt", "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()
```

Comment: Wouldn't `open("file.txt", "rb").read()` actually work (at least in C Python)?  Since there are no leftover references to the file handle, the garbage collector should close the open file.

Comment: @DanielWalker The answer to that is that there is no guarantee that even short-lived garbage will be collected before the interpreter itself terminates. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131055/will-garbage-collector-delete-reference-after-read).